# I want to add ltr rtl option in my react app how will i add postcss rtl plugin in react app you can see required plugin link from below

Tags: reactjs, postcss

I need to add this postcss-rtl in react  app but i dont know where should i need to put this code.
this is the plugin which i am looking to add in my react project 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-rtl#simple-properties

any one have video link for this or https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bav5rr link for this??

Comment: please any advice????

Comment: It depends on your set up. What are you using to build your React app?